# Lower limit under \mathbb

Tags: overleaf

I am wondering how to change this code `\mathbb{E}_{x\in G}` so that `x\in G` appears under `\mathbb{E}`. I tried to add `\limits` but it does not work.

Thank you!

Comment: You wrote, "I tried to add `\limits` but it does not work". For `\limits` to have the desired effect, `\mathbb{E}` must have math status `mathop` ("math operator"). However, the default math status of `\mathbb{E]` is `mathord` ("math ordinary"). Please see my answer for an approach that defines the macro `\E` to have math status `mathop`, making it possible to write `\E\limits_{...}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `$\underset{x\in G}{\mathbb{E}}$`? This requires loading the `amsmath` and `amssymb` packages. The former for `\underset`, the latter for `\mathbb`.

If `\mathbb{E}` is supposed to denote the (conditional or unconditional) expectations operator, I'd like to suggest taking a different approach: Run `\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}` in the preamble and write

```
$\E\limits_{x\in G}$
```

in the body of the document. The utility macro `\DeclareMathOperator*` is defined by the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}} % expectations operator

\begin{document}
$\underset{x\in G}{\mathbb{E}}$ \quad $\E\limits_{x\in G}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`\mathop{{}\mathbb{E}}\limits_{x\in G}` should work